# trouble adding label when appending checkbox's with d3

Tags: checkbox, d3.js

OK I’ve been trying to append some checkbox’s to a div dynamically based on the number of columns in a dataset. So I thought d3 would be the way to go, simply append the input with the appropriate attributes and some text for the label determined from the data.  I’ve tried the following code;

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("input")
.data([11, 22, 33, 44])
.enter().append("input")
.attr("checked", true)
.attr("type", "checkbox")
.attr("id", function(d,i) { return i; })
.attr("onClick", "change(this)")
.attr("for", function(d,i) { return i; })
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Which results in 4 checkboxs on the page but no labels.

What’s really strange is that when I inspect the elements the html generated seems to be what I’m after as shown below.

```
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" id="0" onclick="change(this)" for="0">11</input>
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="change(this)" for="1">22</input>
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="change(this)" for="2">33</input>
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="change(this)" for="3">44</input>
```

When I use this on a page I get exactly what I’m after.

I’m sure I’m missing something extremely simple, but for the life of me I can’t see what it is.  Any help gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem is that you can't put text in between `<input>` tags like that. They are self-closing like `<input />`. You should use the `<label>` element for that text.

Other problem is that ID's *must* begin with a letter (at least, before HTML5), so `id="1"` won't work, but `id=a1"` will.

That said, this code solves those two problems

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("input")
.data([11, 22, 33, 44])
.enter()
.append('label')
    .attr('for',function(d,i){ return 'a'+i; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
.append("input")
    .attr("checked", true)
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return 'a'+i; })
    .attr("onClick", "change(this)");
```

Comment: DanPan thanks for your prompt answer, it worked a treat, although I took the function a + i and included that as the text function. (I suspect you split the steps to address each of the problems you mentioned separately).

Comment: What if you want the input checkbox to come before the text?

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use `<label>` --

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("input")
  .data([11, 22, 33, 44])
  .enter().append("label")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .append("input")
  .attr("checked", true)
  .attr("type", "checkbox")
  .attr("id", function(d,i) { return i; })
  .attr("onClick", "change(this)")
  .attr("for", function(d,i) { return i; });
```

Comment: Lars thank you very much I tried to append label in a similar way, but obviously not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question, but I wanted to give an easy solution as the others weren't working for me...

You can append the label to the checkbox initially, and then after that is complete you can add the text to the label which will then append the text after the checkbox instead of before:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("input")
.data([11, 22, 33, 44])
.enter()
.append("label")
.append("input")
.attr("checked", true)
.attr("type", "checkbox")
.attr("id", function(d,i) { return i; })
.attr("onClick", "change(this)")
.attr("for", function(d,i) { return i; });

d3.selectAll("label").text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like stated before, you cannot add text into a `<input>` tag. My solution was to add the checkbox in a .html() call. Like so:

```
d3.select('body').selectAll('label')
  .data([11, 22, 33, 44])
  .enter().append('label')
  .html(function(d, i) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" checked=true id="' + i + '" onClick="change(this) for="' + i + '">' + d;
  })
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `span` element to house the text to be displayed to the right of each checkbox.
Here we assume you have a div with `id=some_div` to which you'd like to append the checkboxes

```
var filter_controls_div_name="some_div";
var filter_controls__div=d3.selectAll("#"+filter_controls_div_name);
var date=null;
var field_value=null;
var field_value__list=[11,22,33,44];
for(var i=0;i<field_value__list.length;i++)
{
    field_value=field_value__list[i];
    var field__checkbox__div=filter_controls__div
        .append("div")
        .attr("class","checkbox")
    ;
    var field__checkbox__div__label=field__checkbox__div
        .append("label")
        .attr("class","field__label")
    ;
    var field__checkbox__div__label__input=field__checkbox__div__label
        .append("input")
        .attr("type","checkbox")
        .attr("checked","true")
        .attr("for",""+i)
        .attr("field_value",field_value)
        .attr("value",field_value)
    ;
    field__checkbox__div__label
        .append("span")
        .text(field_value)
    ;
    field__checkbox__div__label__input
        .on(
            "change"
            ,function(d)
            {
                var checkbox__element=d3.select(this);
                console.log((date=new Date()).toISOString()
                    +", checkbox__element.property(\"checked\") is:"+(checkbox__element.property("checked"))
                );
                if(checkbox__element.property("checked"))
                {
                    //do something when this checkbox is checked.
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something when this checkbox is unchecked.
                }
            }
        )
    ;
}
```