# Adding form input fields using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new new to D3. I am trying to add input fields inside a svg element(rectangle) using d3.js. Please let me know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Have a look at this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054403/trouble-adding-label-when-appending-checkboxs-with-d3).  It uses checkbox's instead of input fields but they are similar.  Ah, I've just read that properly, you might need to use a foreign object for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this using svg:foreignObject, but you don't really want to use that since it's poorly supported. If you know that you're only going to deploy on browsers that support svg:foreignObject, then you can put any HTML inside of it. Otherwise, you'll need to use traditional DOM elements on a div on a z-index above your SVG and place them using CSS left: and top: in the way that you would place svg:rect elements using x and y.