# Dynamically create radio buttons using d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radio-button

I know how to create the radio buttons to appear dynamically without using d3 js. But how can I create the label text of the radio buttons using d3? Also after creating, how to add them to the radio button?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054403/trouble-adding-label-when-appending-checkboxs-with-d3) might help, just change check box to radio button

Answer (score 4):

```
var shapeData = ["Triangle", "Circle", "Square", "Rectangle"], 
    j = 3;  // Choose the rectangle as default

// Create the shape selectors
var form = d3.select("body").append("form");

labels = form.selectAll("label")
    .data(shapeData)
    .enter()
    .append("label")
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .insert("input")
    .attr({
        type: "radio",
        class: "shape",
        name: "mode",
        value: function(d, i) {return i;}
    })
    .property("checked", function(d, i) {return i===j;});
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/54559btv/)

Comment: Thanks Roshan. I want the text to appear after the radio button and each button to appear in a new line. Can you tell how to do that?